# Compute checksum for Bech32 address

Tags: bech32-address, p2wpkh, checksum

The [Bitcoin Wiki page for Bech32 addresses](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32) explains how one can create a bech32 address from a public key. In step 6 it says-

> Compute the checksum by using the data from step 5 and the H.R.P (bc for MainNet and tb for TestNet)

I went through the [bip 173 wiki page](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#Bech32) which explains the checksum process. However I do not know python and cannot understand most of it.

How does one compute the checksum? Is there some library I can use? I mainly develop in Java/Kotlin/C++. Either an explanation of the python code on the bip173 page or libraries/code snippets in the languages I develop in will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at the reference implementation section: https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#reference-implementations

It lists implementations for various languages, including [C](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/tree/master/ref/c), [C++](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/tree/master/ref/c++), and [JavaScript](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/tree/master/ref/javascript)

Comment: Just to add to this answer, [this pr](https://github.com/sipa/bech32/pull/40/commits) on the github page has the java example.